# AngularJs:-how to dynamically push images into div and upload it to server in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function, content-management-system

I am trying to implement a Crm kind of application..I have implemented a small  feature in which I can select a div from various options. I have given a button to push the image in the div and also ng-style to set the properties.

The problem is I have used ng-model to push the image in the div..Now because of this when I am trying to push images into a new div I am getting the same image over and over again.Can anyone please give the solution to this

The issue is how do I control the image and the parameters which are given by the user and simultaneously display the same thing in the UI.

The below is my code.. cms.html:-

```
      <div id="picture_container" style="display:none">
            <div>Display Picture 1:
            <input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="picFile" name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'" required="">
            <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
            </div>
            <div>Display Picture 2:
            <input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="picFile1"  name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'" required="">
            <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
            </div>
            <div>Display Picture 3:
            <input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="picFile2"  name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'" required="">
            <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="home-page container" id="admin-cont" style="margin-bottom: 50px;padding-top: 20px;">
        <div ng-repeat="layout in selectedLayouts track by $index" class="" style="margin-bottom: 35px;position:relative;">
            <div ng-if="picFile" class="internal" ng-style="{'color': myColor || '#000','left':myLeft || '50%','top':myTop || '50%',
            'font-size':myFont || '14px'}" style="position:absolute;" contenteditable="true">{{myText}}</div>
            <div ng-if="picFile" class="internal" ng-style="{'color': myColor || '#000','left':myLeft || '50%','top':myTop || '50%',
            'font-size':myFont || '14px'}" style="position:absolute;padding-top:14px;" contenteditable="true">{{myText1}}</div>
          <ng-include src="layout" class></ng-include>
        </div>
      </div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid-12">
  <div class="row" id="grid-121">
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <!-- <img ngf-src="picFile" class="img img-responsive"> -->
      <ng-repeat="imageSource in imageSources track by $index" />
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteRow($index, layout)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid-8-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile" class="img img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile1" class="img img-responsive">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteRow($index, layout)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid-6-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile" class="img img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile1" class="img img-responsive">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteRow($index, layout)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid-4-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile" class="img img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile1" class="img img-responsive">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteRow($index, layout)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid-4-4-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile" class="img img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile1" class="img img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-click='selectedDiv($event)' style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
      <img ngf-src="picFile2" class="img img-responsive">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteRow($index, layout)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

the below is my javascript code:-

```
$scope.items = ['grid-12', 'grid-6-6', 'grid-4-8', 'grid-8-4', 'grid-4-4-4'];
$scope.selectedLayouts = [];

$scope.open = function() {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'layoutTemplateModal.html',
    controller: $scope.LayoutModalCtrl,
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {
      items: function() {
        return $scope.items;
      }
    }
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
    $scope.selectedLayouts.push(selectedItem);

  }, function() {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });

};
```

Please help me out..
Thanks

Comment: can you create a plunkr for this?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich The code itself is very huge and using multiple js files to run..The above is just a snippet of the code

Comment: it's very hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Both JS code and markup are vague. Some simple example of what is happening would help. then you could explain what you want to happen...

Comment: I guess the code you published is not related to your question, it will be nice to see what `selectedDiv($event)` does.

Comment: @Catmandu please do use some effort to narrow down the snippet. Maybe you also narrow down the problem and thus ease the find of a solution. It is a pain, but worth it.

Comment: @mico surely I will..understand the issue with the long code.. Will update you all asap

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't enough code shown to narrow down where `selectedItem` comes from in your modal controller , the following should help.

Use `angular.copy()` to prevent pushing the same object reference into array

Try changing:

```
$scope.selectedLayouts.push(selectedItem);
```

To:

```
$scope.selectedLayouts.push(angular.copy(selectedItem));
```